# Pandas updating a column with .loc does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

As far as I understood it is preferable to update the column values using `.loc` method rather than slicing `[]`, because of the potential SettingWithCopy issue. When I use slicing I frequently get these warnings, and I understand that there is a concern when using multindexing.

However, when I am using .loc method, my column is not updated when the column's values are used in the right-hand side:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'A':['2023-01-01','2023-01-02']},[0,1])

a
Out[128]: 
        A
0  2023-01-01
1  2023-01-02

a.dtypes
Out[130]: 
A    object
dtype: object
```

When I am running either of the following commands to convert object into the datetime, the dtype of the column "A" remains object. Thus there is no effect:

```
a.loc[:,'A']=pd.to_datetime(a.loc[:,'A'])
a.loc[:,'A']=pd.to_datetime(a['A'])
```

When I am using

```
a['A']=pd.to_datetime(a['A'])
```

My dtype is converted into datetime. I am curious why .loc method does not work in this case?

Thanks

Comment: That's because [.loc method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is to access a dataframe by label, not to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `a.loc[:,'A']` the dtype of the `Series` will not change because you modify only values. You slice your `Series` (even if you select all rows with `:`) so the container will remain the same. However, the type of each individual value will change from `string` to `Timestamp`.

This is the same for any operations where the left part is sliced (not only for `DatetimeIndex`):

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['3', '5']})

b.loc[:, 'B'] = pd.to_numeric(b.loc[:, 'B'])
# OR
b.loc[:, 'B'] = b.loc[:, 'B'].astype(int)
# OR
b.loc[:, 'B'] = b['B'].astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> b
   B
0  3
1  5

>>> b.dtypes
B    object
dtype: object

>>> b.loc[0, 'B']
3

>>> type(b.loc[0, 'B'])
int
```

This becomes more obvious if you use a slice like `[0:2]` or a specific index like `0` with `loc`. In this case, you understand why the dtype of the container won't change if you change some values and not all values.

Comment: ok, can you recommend how to convert string to datetime so that I can apply .dt method to work with the dates? Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense

Comment: Use `a['A']=pd.to_datetime(a['A'])` as you already did. After that, you can use the `dt` accessor to manipulate dates. Sometimes, you have to use `errors='coerce'` as parameter of `pd.to_datetime` if some of your values are not convertible.

Comment: ok, thanks. I am just keep getting these SettingWithCopy warnings, so I was curious if there is preferred way to change the column type

Comment: It's an another problem. When you slice your dataframe (get a subset of columns, for example), you should use `.copy()` to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Check the output of `df._is_copy` and `df.is_view` to check if some of your dataframe are a copy or a view.